# Convert a PHP image resource to a new Asset

Tags: assets

I am trying to merge two images and save it as a new asset and I am using the PHP function called "imagecopymerge" (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) however thats returning a "resource" and I have tried figuring out how I can turn that "resource" into something I can use to save using perhaps $tempath?

```
$newAsset = new Asset();
$newAsset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
$newAsset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);
$newAsset->tempFilePath = $tempPath;
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($newAsset);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to save the image to the filesystem and use that path as $tempPath.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php